# SQL Query not filtering right data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query:

```
SELECT `gift_donations`.*, `scholarships`.`name` AS scholarship_name
FROM (`gift_donations`)
LEFT
    OUTER JOIN `scholarships` scholarships ON `scholarships`.`id` =
    `gift_donations`.`scholarship_id`
WHERE `gift_donations`.`contact_id` =  '13'
AND
    `gift_donations`.`in_memory` REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+' OR in_honor REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+'
ORDER BY
    `gift_donations`.`id` desc
```

As you can see, here I am trying to get **only those records whose `contact_id` is `13`** but the problem is that the result set also contains other records whose `contact_id` isn't `13`

Why is it so, is it because of `REGEXP` or I am not making my query the way it should be to bring back only those records whose `contact_id` is `13` or any other number that I want ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AND` takes precedence over `OR`. You should surround your second `AND` clause with parentheses like such

```
(`gift_donations`.`in_memory` REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+' OR in_honor REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+')
```

As it is, you have essentially written following where clause

```
A and B or C
```

wich due to operator precedence is equivalent to

```
(A and B) or (C)
```

and has to be changed to

```
(A) and (B or C)
```

You can look for all operators precedence in the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

*Note that it's always a good idea to be explicit using parentheses*

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket.

```
WHERE `gift_donations`.`contact_id` =  '13'
AND
   ( `gift_donations`.`in_memory` REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+' OR in_honor REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+')
ORDER BY
    `gift_donations`.`id` desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put parentheses () in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT `gift_donations`.*, `scholarships`.`name` AS scholarship_name
FROM (`gift_donations`)
LEFT
    OUTER JOIN `scholarships` scholarships ON `scholarships`.`id` =
    `gift_donations`.`scholarship_id`
WHERE  `gift_donations`.`contact_id` =  '13'
AND
    ( `gift_donations`.`in_memory` REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+' OR in_honor REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+' )
ORDER BY
    `gift_donations`.`id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be fetching those records whose contact_id are not 13

```
OR in_honor REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+'
```